# If else statement troubles in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I am trying to input a seat number of "15"  into this function and get the char value of 'A'. However, for some reason every time I input a number that should be a type 'A'(because its remainder doesn't equal any of the aforementioned values) it gets stuck in the 'M' else if statement. I really do not understand why and would like some help if you have time :)

```
char whatTypeOfSeat(int seatNumber){
   if((seatNumber % 6) == 0 || seatNumber % 6 == 1 || seatNumber == 1) {
    typeOfSeat =  'W';
    }
    else if((seatNumber % 6) == 2 || (seatNumber % 6) == 5|| seatNumber == 5,2 ) {
     typeOfSeat = 'M';
      }
    else {
    typeOfSeat = 'A';
    }
    return typeOfSeat;

}
```

Comment: What is this: `seatNumber == 5,2` ?

Comment: `seatNumber == 5,2` ?? it tests for 2 which is always true...

Comment: Where is `typeOfSeat` defined?

Comment: Thanks, that helped, i for some reason thought i can append on to one equals statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
seatNumber == 5,2
```

If you want to check against both values, you need separate conditionals

```
else if((seatNumber % 6) == 2 || (seatNumber % 6) == 5|| seatNumber == 5 || seatNumber == 2 ) {
```